# Can I use any USB charger with my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, usb

I'm not sure its the right place to ask but, I just wondered whether I can charge my iPhone Xr with my Samsung adapter. I understand it works and no harm is done to the iphone.

I know that the iPhone transmitting info about voltage and current between the phone and adapter so that the current and voltage wont exceed iPhone limits?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  As it's currently written, your question is difficult to understand.  Please see [ask] for important info on asking questions here.  You can [edit] your question to add the additional info.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly...

A power adapter with a USB port on it will charge anything that that can be charged via USB. So, probably...

That said it is important to note that some USB chargers don't provide enough wattage to charge a device or charge it quickly enough. Also if the usb charger has just a mini/micro USB cable on it then no, as iPhones have *Lightning" connectors **not** USB connectors.

There is also the issue with cheap, knock-off chargers that are constructed poorly and will damage anything that are plugged into them.

That said a USB charger that is designed to charge a Samsung phone should work as long as it has a standard USB port on it that you can plug a lightning cable into.

Comment: thanks for the response. well, i already said i know that using samsung adapter for iphone shloud be ok. but i asked about the protocol  of the adapter phone communication. it must be universal protocol because both iphone and samsung communicate wirh the adapter. and i mentioned java allthough i know its not a protocol but it is multiplatform programming language...

Comment: USB is USB, any protocol that is there is built into the USB standard and doesn't cange from device to device

Answer (score 1):

USB Charging is a universal standard.

The quality of your cable is more important than the charging brick when it comes to whether your phone will be fine when charging.

As long as you have a MFI certified lightning cable you should be fine. The samsung charger should actually charge you faster than the 5w charger that comes with the XR.

Also FYI in your original question you asked about java for transferring information. Java is a programming language not a protocol.